# GNU GCC 4.6(.1) compiler on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, gnu, osx-lion

Pretty new to this kind of development. Wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction. As far as I can see it, using MacPorts has an error where it doesn't work. However, I was reading around and saw this: http://beardedcodewarrior.net/2011/07/25/building-gcc-4-6-1-on-mac-os-x-lion/ but still couldn't get it to work. When I executed make for gcc, it took over 3 hours to complete and then once I execute sudo make install, it completed successfully but when I try gcc --version, it still says gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00). I need the 4.6.1 version!

Comment: which gcc? i don't think you've used the gcc you've compiled. try to specify the full path.

Comment: Dyno Fu is probably right. Do a `which gcc` to see which one you're actually using.

Comment: Have you configured GCC to install in a custom location? It’s usually a bad idea to overwrite system’s GCC (which apparently you haven’t). If you’ve configured it to use a custom install location, see if that location (e.g. /opt/bin or /usr/local/bin) contains `gcc`.

Comment: Since Mac OS X defaults to `bash` instead of `tcsh` or `csh`, I'd *strongly* recommend the `bash` built-in command `type` instead of `which`. The `which` command uses the `csh` setup (e.g. `.cshrc` file) to set its search path instead of the `bash` setup (e.g. `.profile`, `.bashrc`). Use `help type` to see all its options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three likely possibilities:

1. It installed correctly and went into a directory earlier in your `$PATH` than your previous GCC installation, but Bash's internal hash table entry is still pointing to the old GCC.
2. It installed correctly but went into a directory later in your `$PATH` than your previous GCC installation.
3. In installed correctly, but the executable is not named `gcc`.

If #1, just run the command `hash -r` and try again.  In order to avoid frequent `$PATH` lookups, Bash uses a hash table to map executable names into executable locations.  When you install a new executable earlier in your `$PATH` with the same name as one later in the `$PATH`, Bash doesn't know about it.  Running `hash -r` says "clear out your hash table".  Alternatively, you can just run `hash -d gcc` to say "forget about gcc in your hash table".

If #2, then you either need to execute gcc by its full name (e.g. `/opt/local/bin/gcc`), or modify your `$PATH` so that the directory containing the new gcc is earlier than the directory of your existing gcc.  Assuming you installed MacPorts normally, that should already be done for you—MacPorts puts `/opt/local/bin` earlier in your `$PATH` than `/usr/bin` by modifying your `~/.bash_profile` startup file.

If #3, then figure out what name the executable was given.  It was almost certainly given a name prefixed with gcc, so if you type gcc and then hit the tab key twice, Bash will give you a list of all of the commands that begin with gcc.  It's quite likely it was given a name likw `gcc-4.6` or `gcc-mp-4.6`.

Comment: I'd recommend installing a custom gcc in `/usr/local` (by giving the `--prefix=/usr/local` flag to `./configure`) and checking your `$PATH` to make sure `/usr/local/bin` comes before `/usr/bin`. Also, to show *all* the gccs that your shell can see, use the command `type -a gcc`, which will show you the paths to all commands named `gcc`. Without the `-a` option, it will show you just the one that will execute if you type `gcc` on the command line.

Comment: Okay thank you both for you help so far. I ran type -a gcc and found 2 versions. I want to use the second one which is in /usr/local/bin/gcc. When I executed /usr/local/bin/gcc -v it shows up as 4.6.1. How can I modify my $PATH file to make it default to that one first?

Comment: Actually, I modified my $PATH file, it looks like this `/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin`

But when I do GCC --version I still have 4.2.1

Comment: @Bert: What is the output of `which gcc`?  Have you ran `hash -r`?

Comment: Hah, Would you look at that. I come back to my computer an hour later and now it works. I even ran `hash -r` a bunch of times to no avail. Weird. It now works with 4.6.1 thanks to you and the other commenters suggestions!